# ZeroMQ PULL get all messages in queue

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I have a large (~100) number of PUSH "clients" that periodically (~1/s) send a message to a PULL "server". The server processes the messages in batches at a rate of ~2 batches per second. The batch size is not fixed - ideally I would like to process all the messages in the queue at each iteration. My code for getting all the messages in the queue is as follows:

```
buffer = []
while True:
  try:
    buffer.append(socket.recv_pyobj(zmq.NOBLOCK))
  except zmq.ZMQError as e:
    break
print(len(buffer))
```

This seems to work, but the buffer lengths vary wildly in between iterations. Normally, I would expect to see ~50 messages read each time. However, I often see many iterations with <10 messages, and then one with a very large number (~1000). I suspect I'm doing something wrong regarding buffering or something like that as this should not be happening.

Answer (score 0):

### Highly dynamic changes on receiving side?

My suspect is the **`PULL`**-side fair-queue-ing policy, hard-wired inside the **`.Context()`** low-level data-pump, that serves ( follows ) this mandatory duty-cycle for all the `.connect()`-ed peers.

Unless you are able to somehow equalise the latencies with which the feeding **`PUSH`**-ers are sending their respective messages, the fair-queued receiving cycle will, exactly in the way you have reported, manifest the ones, who did not `PUSH` "in time" their next message.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're saying (including what "nivelise" means). Can you explain in a bit more detail?

In any case, I've alleviated this by first doing 50 blocking `recv`s - now the variation is in the 50-150 range which is reasonable. This modification doesn't seem to add any penalty to the time spent pulling per iteration

Comment: ~ equalise latencies, i.e. all having ( almost ) the same

Comment: Is there a way to disable the fair-queuing, or some other option I can use to improve performance?

Comment: What is, in your terms, a measure of performance of this distributed-system and what metrics do you propose to use for it? If designing a code with both a zero-control of the flow of incoming-events and zero-(own)-control of the processing of incoming tasks on the receiving PULL-er side, what is your way of thinking about the said "improving performance"?